# Where is the specification for GWT HTMLPanel UiBinder XML?

Tags: java, gwt, xsd, uibinder

I am trying to find what child elements and attributes I can add to:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder" xmlns:gwt="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">
    <gwt:HTMLPanel whatAttribsGoHere="???">
        <!-- ??? -->
    </gwt:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

I found [this *similar* question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10497965/xml-schema-for-gwt-uibinder), however when I go to the [recommended link](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/releases/2.0/user/src/com/google/gwt/uibinder/resources/UiBinder.xsd?r=6837) I see no mention of `HTMLPanel`. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

**Edit**: I'm not looking for any GWT gurus/Google employees to simply *tell* me what elements/attributes fit here, I'm looking to *learn where* I can go to find this stuff out on my own! I say this because I could just as easily ask the same question for any other widget!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've posted an answer on the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10497965/xml-schema-for-gwt-uibinder) that explains the general rules. `HTMLPanel` though might be one of the rare widgets whose usage in UiBinder is not documented, while being the widget that UiBinder *empowers* the most.

If you want to learn what specific attributes and content you can put in `HTMLPanel` (besides *bean setter attributes*), you can then look at the the code for `HTMLPanelParser`. You'll see that you can use a `tag` attribute that matches the similarly named constructor argument, and the content is a mix of HTML and widgets (UiBinder will replace the widgets with placeholder HTML elements in the HTML string passed to the `HTMLPanel` constructor, and then call `addAndReplaceElement` to put the child widgets in the panel).

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Broyer - I guess I'm shocked that this isn't documented somewhere. Any reasons why? Is it just a lack of manpower? From a GWT newcomer's perspective, it would be very helpful to have a reference to go off of when using UiBinder. Right now it feels like I'm stumbling around in the dark, and going to the source code of the Widget's respective parser feels like 3-sides-around-the-barn. Just my two cents, but thanks for the help.